# Determine if a file exists within a folders file-path that is contained in a Cell on Excel for a range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba, directory, filepath

I am keen to add functionality to an excel spreadsheet I am building to track compliance.

My idea is proving hard to achieve and after reading loads of articles and posts, I'm very confused.

I have a spreadsheet that has 5 columns, one of these columns will contain filepaths for around 100 folders.

The other columns will be files that need to be in these folders - 4 files with the same reference in their titles.

I would like to press a button, and have the Sub run on startup to go through each of these folders and ensure the compliance files are present.
I have tried to adapt some code, but I'm struggling with a few things.

1. How do I actually do this?
2. How do use the *dir()* funtion to pull a filepath from a cell?
3. How do I reference the cell next to the cell currently being investigated
4. How do I cycle this through a Range of cells - I.e (A2:A200)
5. It will need to read from the A column, but return a Boolean value (1 or 0) to a different cell on the same row, how will I accomplish this.

Here's where I got to, this is some code I found online.

```
Sub IsItThere()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim fileName As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim C As String

Cell = E3: E200  'The range of Filepaths
For i = 3 To 200
Do

C = Cell(i)

fileName = Dir(C)
While fileName <> ""
    
    If fileName = Dir()(C + "January*") Then   'Does it contain the key phrase
    B(i) = "1"
Else
    B(i) = "0"         'Make the cell next door to the cell with the current filepath become 1

 End If
i = i + 1
    fileName = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: The code you found online has *lots* of issues. I'd suggest you scrap it and start over.

Comment: When I say I got the code, it was good code, it worked for their purpose. I have clearly butchered it since I found it. Many thanks to ExcelOffTheGrid...

Comment: @BigBen Does the premise actually make sense? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, very possible.

Comment: 3. Cell as Range has method [Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset), so next right cell will be Cell.Offset(0,1), next down - Cell.Offset(1,0)

4. Usually it is written like this
     For Each rCell In Range("A2:A200")
            ...
     Next rCell

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will get text from each cell in range A2:A200 on active sheet, check that last symbol in this string is a Path Separator and add it if need.

Then for four cells at right check that file exists and put result (TRUE or FALSE) to cells in columns F:I

```
Sub IsItThere()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFileName As String
Dim i As Integer
    For Each rCell In [A2:A200].Cells()
        sPath = rCell.Text
        If Right(sPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then sPath = sPath & Application.PathSeparator
        For i = 1 To 4
            sFileName = Trim(rCell.Offset(0, i).Text)
            rCell.Offset(0, i + 4) = (Dir(sPath & sFileName) <> vbNullString)
        Next i
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

So result will be like this:
[image: Example of result]

Comment: Hey @JohnSUN thanks for this, i believe i can adapt this to fit my needs. this is very helpful.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with this, i'm now trying to add to the file path in A1, with 2 columns behind it, in the same row. In the For Each loop, i'm trying to put this into it, to reference each folder name in the file path. So it would be Offset -1 = Firstname and Offset -2 = Surname to create a (Surname, Firstname) to add to the filepath.

FirstN = rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
LastN = rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
ConName = (LastN & ", " & FirstN)
Range("A3").Value = ConName

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I read this several times but didn't get it. Are you having difficulties with the last operator? Where Range ("A3"). Value = ConName?

Comment: Hi John, Ignore my last comment please.

In the original code you sent me i am not having any luck :-( I have created text files named like your jpg named above. Do i need to put the .txt in the cell, is there a way it could search a key phrase in the filename instead? so if a compliance doc was called a 'WSP' it would validate file names like 'markWSP' or 'Mark wsp copy'?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What should a macro do if there is more than one file containing the WSP in name in the folder? Take the first one? Take the last one? Take everything?

Comment: Hey John, there would only be 1 of the file in each directory.

Comment: I've written some more code, it's getting messy  you're code is still the benchmark. But if it's cool I'll show you what I've done and maybe you could explain why the logic isn't working for me 